# error code in e:systemmd-shim post removal script process returned error exit status 2

Tags: dpkg

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and when I run an update request it says unable to do a full up date. it returns 
Error Code   Error in E:systemd-shim post removal script process returned error exit status 2 what is the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get a problem with the post removal script of a package you can go look at that post removal script and look what is causing it (or even bypass everything and force a package removal at your own risk, this is very useful to fix your package manager for the moment thou). This post scripts are located at:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/[the package that is causing troubles].postrm
```

Once there you should look at the code that is returning, in your example the console is throwing a status 2 code so you should go look for a:

```
... || return 2
```

And look why the package cannot be removed.

If you want to bypass the checker and just want the package to be removed at any cost so you can fix your package manager, look for the if statement inside the post removal script and comment all of it, the just put a return 0, save it and run one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt autoremove
```